# Install gym atari in Amazon SageMaker

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, amazon-sagemaker, openai-gym

I am trying to install Gym Atari environments on a Amazon SageMaker instance. I run the following script in a jupyter notebook:

```
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install gym[atari]
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.atarimania.com/roms/Roms.rar', 'Roms.rar')
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-x64-6.0.2.tar.gz', 'rarlinux-x64-6.0.2.tar.gz')
!tar -xvzf rarlinux-x64-6.0.2.tar.gz
%cd rar
!make
!sudo make install
%cd ..
!unrar x Roms.rar
!mkdir rars
!mv HC\ ROMS.zip rars
!mv ROMS.zip rars
!python -m atari_py.import_roms rars
```

The script upgrades pip, install gym with the Atari dependencies, fetch the Roms, install unrar to extract the file Roms.rar and then run the command `python -m atari_py.import_roms rars`.

An issue arise when I run `python -m atari_py.import_roms rars`. The output is the following:

```
rar/
rar/unrar
rar/acknow.txt
rar/whatsnew.txt
rar/order.htm
rar/readme.txt
rar/rar.txt
rar/makefile
rar/default.sfx
rar/rar
rar/rarfiles.lst
rar/license.txt
/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/rar
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
cp rar unrar /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/rar’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/unrar’: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
cp rar unrar /usr/local/bin
cp rarfiles.lst /etc
cp default.sfx /usr/local/lib
/home/ec2-user/SageMaker

UNRAR 6.02 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2021 Alexander Roshal


Extracting from Roms.rar

Extracting  HC ROMS.zip                                                 36  OK 
Extracting  ROMS.zip                                                    7 99  OK 
All OK
copying adventure.bin from HC ROMS/BY ALPHABET (PAL)/A-G/Adventure (PAL).bin to /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atari_py/atari_roms/adventure.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atari_py/import_roms.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atari_py/import_roms.py", line 89, in main
    import_roms(args.dirpath)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atari_py/import_roms.py", line 78, in import_roms
    _check_zipfile(f, save_if_matches)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atari_py/import_roms.py", line 23, in _check_zipfile
    process_f(innerf)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/amazonei_pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/atari_py/import_roms.py", line 67, in save_if_matches
    f.seek(0)
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

I did some research but found nothing. I would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: it seems file or disk (file system) is not real file-object and it doesn't have function `seek(0)` to move to the beginning of file. But it seems you have all command on screen so you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a bug in `ZipFile.seek()` in Python 3.7.0: [Python issue #34035](https://bugs.python.org/issue34035).

You need to upgrade to the latest Python 3.7.x release.